# Java Serializable failure

Tags: java, android, serializable

I've have a class called Expression that im trying to serialize using the following load()/save() functions. It used to work fine, after making some changes to my code and the Expression class, a call to `in.readObject()` throws `ClassCastException`.
The error message is:
*java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.io.ObjectStreamClass*

Comment: Unless something is very different on Android Java development, it does not seem to me that you would need to implement your own serializing algorithm for this object. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you attempting to load a serialized object that was saved Before you changed the Expression class definition?

Comment: what ever was stored before has been deleted.
@thatidiotguy what do you mean implement my own algorithm? im just adding implement Serializable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, it feels very bad to store binary data as a String. Try to use a more stable way to store the binary output of the ObjectOutputStream. If you really want to stick with a string formatted approach, try to use Base64 encoding, which is always safe.

---

What I might see as a problem is that you defined the serialUID yourself to a static constant:

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3L;
```

This UID is used to determine if the classes in the class path are compatible with the class of the input object. So what I suspect is that you modified the class without changing the serialVersionUID. That made the ObjectInputStream think that is is compatible, but you are still working with old data. Try to get rid of the old data, and restart with a fresh `save()` call.

---

Are you sure that `Input` is serializable as well? That the UID of that class isn't corrupt?

Comment: using a String is what I can do for now... the issue seems to be the modification of the class which causes some failure. the use of a string worked fine

Comment: I've tried modifying serialVersionUID several times, it didnt have any effect. that old that has been deleted a long time ago. through debug i can see that the new data is being saved but the i try to load it readObject() throws an exception,

Comment: If it is possible, can you share Input class? Also Expression and Input classes are not inner classes, right?

Comment: Some very bad advice here. There's no reason to modify serialVersionUID unless you deliberately want to cause an incompatibility with all old data, and you should never want to do that. Serialization has extensive support for class versioning, which any designer/user of Serialization should be familiar with. If by any chance you've gone outside the permissible compatible clas s changes, which are extensive, you should make every attempt to preserve compatibility via the various extra techniques available. Wantonly changing the serialVersionUID just betrays unfamiliarity with the system.

Answer (score 0):

it seems serializable does not like NULL values in the fields of the class members.
if i make sure that all class members have actual memory it does not fail.